# Can we find a general $\delta$ to prove the continuity of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, continuity

Polynomials are continuous functions. In other words, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $a$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$, $|P(x)-P(a)|<\epsilon$ where $P(x)$ is a function of the form

$$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$

The proof of this is usually done via limit theorems and mathematical induction, which circumvents the difficulty of finding $\delta$.

My question is, is it possible to prove the continuity of polynomials by *explicitly* finding a $\delta$ (a closed form), in terms of $n$, $a$, $a_i$ and $\epsilon$ where we have $\delta = \min(....)$.

If this is too ambitious, are there special cases (with, say, quadratics)?

Comment: Your quantifiers are mixed up : you can't find a $\delta$ that works for all $\epsilon$ since it would mean that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $P(x)=P(a)$ which is impossible except when $P$ is constant.

Comment: @CaptainLama Good catch, I'll fix that

Comment: Yes, one can find an explicit $\delta$.

Comment: How about taking $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{n\cdot\text{max}_i|a_i|}$?

Comment: I like your question!

Comment: @Larara Your $\delta$ can't possibly work, since it's independent of $a$. But not all polynomials are uniformly continuous over $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: @David you're right. I think that we must separate in two cases: $|x-a|<1$ and $|x-a|\geq 1$, like in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $|x - a| \leq \delta \leq 1$. We have 
$$
\begin{align*}
|P(x) - P(a)| &= \left|\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i(x - a)(x^{i-1} + x^{i-2}a + \dots + a^{i-1})\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{i = 1}^n i|a_i||x - a| \max(|x|^{i-1}, |a|^{i-1}) \\
&\leq |x-a|\max(|x|^{n-1},|a|^{n-1},1)\sum_{i=1}^n i|a_i| \\
&\leq \delta (|a| + 1)^{n-1}n^2 \max_{i \geq 1}(|a_i|).
\end{align*}$$
So (assuming $P(x)$ is non-constant) you can choose $\delta = \min(1,\epsilon/M)$, where $M = (|a|+1)^{n-1}n^2 \max_{i \geq 1}(|a_i|)$.

What I wrote works, but it might be possible to do this a bit more cleanly by using $|P(x) - P(a)| \leq |x-a| \max_{y \in I_{a,x}} |P'(y)|$, where $I_{a,x}$ is either $[a,x]$ or $[x,a]$.

Comment: David, could you please explain with more detail how you get the last inequality? $|x-a|\max(|x|^{n-1},|a|^{n-1},1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i|a_i| \le \delta(|a|+1)^{n-1}n^2\max_{n \ge 1}(|a_i|)$ ?